# What could the component be if the diode test result shows finite voltages for both orientations?

Tags: power-supply, pcb, identification, multimeter, reverse-engineering

I was trying to identify a 2 terminal component using the diode test in DMM- It measured 0.420V in one direction and 1.88V in other direction.

[image]

I am not sure what this component could be.  For other regular diodes, it is clearly showing 0.7V and OL (overlimit) while doing the diode test.

Comment: First guess would be a low-voltage zener, but it could also be a failed diode--or a failed anything else, really.

Comment: It's probably fine; you're probably measuring some other part of the circuitry when in reverse-bias.  Easiest way to tell is remove it and test it out-of-circuit.

Comment: The component can't be measured in-circuit, because other components will be in parallel with it so they affect the measurements.

Comment: Desolder one side and measure again.